# Dnsmasq port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, dnsmasq

#### My current configuration

`site.example.net 192.168.1.1`

#### What I want to do

`site.example.net:10000 192.168.1.2`

#### My question

Knowing that I've already tried this type of configuration in `/etc/hosts` and in `dnsmasq.conf` and it didn't worked, is it possible to do some simple port forwarding like this with dnsmasq ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS tools such as `dnsmasq` concern themselves only with mapping between domain names and IP addresses. They do not (and cannot) map port numbers in any way.